# Migrating SharePoint Farm to new Sever Environment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

I have been tasked to upgrade one of our current SharePoint Environments (MOSS 2007) to the latest and greatest version of SharePoint 2013. This current SharePoint Environment is as follows:

- Database Server is 64bit Windows Server 2003 running SQL Server
  8.0.2282
- Application Server is 32bit Windows Server 2003 R2

What I have done so far:

Using Pro SharePoint Migration - Moving From MOSS 2007 to SharePoint Server 2010 - S. Malik, S. Sistla as a guide I have attempted several of the migration paths in the book. So not be too verbose I will sum up and say that because our current environment is production and can’t be taken down, moving the SharePoint Farm to an upgraded Virtual Environment hasn't worked at all.

What I am planning on doing next:

I have decided to make a copy of the SharePoint Farm and query each of the Databases and update everything in each database that references the current environment with the equivalent information from the new environment. Once that is complete I will reinstall SharePoint pointing to this updated Farm.

So my questions are:

1. Will this path work?
2. What issues do you thing I will run into going
   down this path?
3. Is there another migration path to take that I
       haven’t already attempted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That will absolutely not work (or at the very least not supported at all).  There is also no direct upgrade path between 2007 and 2013.  You'll have to perform an intermediate upgrade to 2010 before upgrading to 2013.  Alternatively, there are vendor tools that will move just the content from 2007 to 2013.  That might be a good option for you.  Whatever you do you need to be sure to practice this to make sure you understand what does and does not get migrated between the versions.

Answer (score 0):

To follow along the lines of Mark, if you are planning a SP2007 to SP2013 migration, a migration tool would certainly be an interesting avenue. I simply wanted to let you know that Sharegate offers a free 15-day trial that might be interesting in your case at least to see what kind of migration tool would suit your needs. http://en.share-gate.com/